# buffer overrun while trying to link two strings together, why do I have this error?

Tags: c, string, memory-management

(in C, using visual studio 2022 preview), I have to do a program that link two strings together. Here's what I did:

1. I wrote two for-loops to count characters of first string and second
   string,
2. I checked (inside the link function if the pointers are null (first and second). If they are null, then "return NULL".
3. I created "char *result". this is a new string and this is the string to be returned. I allocated enough memory to store nprime, nsecond, and 1 more character (the zero terminator). I used a malloc.
4. then, I checked if result is null. if it's null then "return NULL".
5. then, I wrote 2 for-loops to perform the linking between the first string and the second string. And here I got a compiler warning (because I think it's in compile time not in debug time). buffer overrun, the writable size is
   "nprime+nsecond+1" but 2 bytes might be written.
   my theory is that the program is trying to write outside the result-array, so there could be a loss of data, I tried to edit my code, therefore I write "nprime+nsecond+2" instead but it doesn't work, and it keeps showing me the same buffer overrun error.

   ```
   #include <stdlib.h> 

   char* link( const char* first, const char* second) {
   size_t nprime = 0; 
   size_t nsecond = 0; 

   if (first == NULL) {
       return NULL; 
   }
   if (second == NULL) {
       return NULL; 
   }
   for (size_t i = 0; first[i] < '\0'; i++) {
       nprime++; 
   }
   for (size_t i = 0; second[i] < '\0'; i++) {
       nsecond++; 
   }
   char* result = malloc(nprime + nsecond + 1); 
   if (result == NULL) {
       return NULL; 
   }

   for (size_t i = 0; i < nprime; i++) {
       result[i] = first[i]; 
   }
   for (size_t i = 0; i < nsecond; i++) {
       result[nprime + i] = second[i]; 
   }
   result[nprime + nsecond] = 0; 

   return result; 
   }
   ```

this is the main:

```
int main(void) {
char s1[] = "this is a general string  "; 
char s2[] = "this is a general test."; 
char* s; 
    
s = link(s1, s2); 
return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Um, is maybe using stuff like `strlen`, `strcpy` and `strcat` an option?

Comment: `nprime` and `nsecond` are both `0` since you have the wrong ending condition, which should be `first[i] != '\0';` It wasn't an *actual* buffer overrun, just a warning from the compiler, and the output string was a valid `""` empty string.

Comment: it's a programming exercise I have to do in college (I'm at first year of computer engineer) so I can't use library functions. At least, until I learn how to do this stuff manually.

Comment: *engineering (typo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warning is given due to the wrong conditions you defined in the first 2 for loops. The right loops should be as follows:

```c
for (size_t i = 0; first[i] != '\0'; i++) {
    nprime++; 
}
for (size_t i = 0; second[i] != '\0'; i++) {
    nsecond++; 
}
```

With the conditions you defined (i.e. `first[i] < '\0'`) you are just counting how many chars in the given string have an ASCII code lower than the ASCII code of `\0` and exit the loop as soon as you find a char not fulfilling such condition.

Since `'\0'` has ASCII value 0, your nprime and nsecond are never incremented, leading to a malloc with insufficient room for the chars you actually need.

Comment: I edited my code but I still have the green squiggle, if I ignore it the program works as well, is it a visual studio bug?

Comment: I don't use Visual Studio, but I tried to compile the program with gcc and I don't get any warning.